# Spring: rest client for given resource interface

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have **api.jar**  with interfaces annotated with Spring annotations like **org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping** and so on. This **api** is used as a maven dependency. I would like to generate **Rest** client basing on given interfaces or use this interface as a source for some kind of proxy object to consume rest endpoints without manual implementation (**restTemplate** object..)

Comment: Look this: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/api-client-generator-howto

Comment: You can use springfox-swagger2 which will automatically generate the rest clients.